# Missing parts of utf-8 charset in urxvt with VcXsrv

Tags: linux, windows, locale, x-server, urxvt

I am running an Arch Linux server which I connect to from a few Windows machines using VcXsrv so I can run graphical applications (and more customized terminals than what I can get with PuTTY etc). However, I am having some trouble with urxvt and UTF-8 characters from the UTF-8 Dingbats section, namely, they don't render. I use Dingbats to show git status in my shell prompt, and also to display the exit status of commands.

locale.conf:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

locale output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

urxvt configuration (~/.Xdefaults):

```
URxvt*scrollTtyOutput: false
URxvt*scrollWithBuffer: true
URxvt*scrollTtyKeypress: true
URxvt*scrollBar: false
URxvt*cursorBlink: true
URxvt*background: black
URxvt*foreground: green
URxvt*font: xft:Hack:size=10, xft:Unifont:size=10
URxvt*locale: true
URxvt*skipBuiltinGlyphs: true
URxvt*xftAntialias: true
URxvt*saveLines: 10000
URxvt*eightBitInput: false
```

urxvt version information:

```
rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.22 - released: 2016-01-23
options: perl,xft,styles,combining,blink,iso14755,unicode3,encodings=eu+vn+jp+jp-ext+kr+zh+zh-ext,
         fade,transparent,tint,XIM,frills,selectionscrolling,wheel,slipwheel,cursorBlink,
         pointerBlank,scrollbars=plain+rxvt+NeXT+xterm
```

I can see all Latin, Katakana, Hiragana, Hangul, Chinese (traditional, simplified), Cyrillic, Persian (most), Georgian characters, etc. But Dingbats look like this when I print them:

[image: Dingbats not rendering]

I am using zsh in vim-mode if that matters.
Looking on google the only advice I can find is to make sure my locale is set to being UTF-8 and that the fonts have the necessary glyphs. Both I believe I have ensured.

Where could I have gone wrong?

Comment: Do note that the fonts must be available *on the client*, not on the server. (unless you're running a terminal from the server with X server redirection, that is)

Comment: Connecting using `ssh -X` with PuTTY. I installed the fonts on my Arch machine, then copied them and placed them in the correct locations of the VcXsrv installations. Maybe that wasn't the correct way to do that?

Comment: The place where PuTTY is running on needs to have the fonts (that is, the Windows console). And that usually isn't the case. You can run `gnome-terminal` through ssh -X though, and that should render correctly, with the server fonts (I actually use such a configuration!)

Comment: @Paul Stelian The problem is with my urxvt terminals, the PuTTY terminal renders as I expect. From the PuTTY session, I spawn the urxvt terminals, and those are the ones that wont render correctly. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear with that. (I just wanted to show how I was forwarding X in my previous comment)

Comment: I believe urxvt doesn't actually take all fonts into consideration. Are you aware on how to change which font it uses? (it doesn't do it automatically, that's for sure) Also, be sure that the chosen font has those characters (maybe a Noto Mono or similar font?)

Comment: I included my urxvt configuration in the question, as I am not sure where the actual problem resides. I followed some guides online when I set it up (my first time with urxvt), and it seems to render the correct font when visually comparing characters with the glyph maps for each font. I tested the fallback font by temporarily removing the first choice. I also dumped the print-out of the Dingbat test to a file and compared the binary data with the expected byte sequences for the Dingbat characters, and they match.

Comment: And... you sure that Hack font includes dingbats?

Comment: It should, and the fallback definitely does.

Comment: Maybe Hack doesn't have it. Note that it only loads the fallback if the *entire font* is missing, not if some characters are. Maybe change order?

Comment: That's not how I interpreted the information I found on google, so that's very good to know. Thanks. Just ran the Dingbat test after I dropped that font from the list and did `xrdb -load .Xdefaults`. Same result, no Dingbats get printed. (This time I used only Unifont).

Comment: Hmm, try getting some Noto Mono fonts because Noto is known to avoid having boxes (they call Tofu) as much as they can.

Comment: Hm, GNU Unifont has the same goal. I gave Noto Mono a shot (`URxvt*font: xft:Noto\ Mono:size=10`), but the dingbats are still missing.

Comment: Well that is interesting...

Comment: I have tried the characters on my Windows system and *some* only render with specialized fonts, while others don't render at all.

Comment: As of https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp you aren't even in the correct Unicode region (unless there are dingbats there too)

Comment: Ah I see... Characters 61440 and on (u+F000 and on) are the *private use* plane, where characters mean different things on different systems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from using characters which are in the Private Use plane of Unicode, which is not guaranteed to have anything particular in that. Windows XP systems could explicitly edit the fonts there with the `eudcedit` command, Macs have an Apple logo in one of the 6400 characters in that plane and, simply put, you are using the wrong dingbats.

The correct dingbats are from 9985 to 10175 decimal (2701 to 27bf hex).

Comment: That was a really stupid failure in my test, but, it didn't quite resolve my problem 100%, results with Noto Mono and Unifont (in that order): [Imgur: results](http://i.imgur.com/Kw9QXUV.png)

Comment: Hmm, now the problem does get interesting...

Comment: On my Windows Console, only 3 fonts worked: NSimSun,
MS Gothic,
SimSun-ExtB

Comment: Wouldn't it be up to my X-server (VcXsrv) to render the fonts through? Since it's an urxvt console.

Comment: The X server indeed is the one responsible for rendering fonts. However, having the common fonts where some do cover them indeed (try Noto Mono again) is a nice thing. And it's also possible fonts do get pushed into the server by the app.

Comment: You put me on the correct path there. I started digging deeper in my X-server (VcXsrv), both code and log, and managed to get this line out of it during startup: `Warning: Locale not supported by X, falling back to 'C' locale.`.